# KnockoutJS Accessing an array of objects in a separate class

Tags: arrays, object, knockout.js

So i have 2 classes, users and health readings. i made a array of user objects with an array of readings inside it.i just want access to the date and weight in the reading array, i have been trying for a long time to figure this out! please help this simple problem is driving me nuts!

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function Reading(theDate,theWeight)
{

    self.theDate=ko.observable(theDate);
    self.theWeight=ko.observable(theWeight);
}

function User(name,weight,date) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.date = date;
    self.weight = ko.observable(weight);
     self.theReadings = ko.observableArray([
        new Reading(12,13)
    ]);

}
    // Editable data
      self.users = ko.observableArray([
        new User("George",1,2012),
        new User("Bindu",2,2012)
    ]);
    /this alerts an object but i dont know how to access the weight/date variable
    alert(self.users()[0].theReadings()[0]);

    self.readings = ko.observableArray([
        new Reading(12,13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missed a few things on this one.

Here ya go.

http://jsfiddle.net/EN7y4/3/

Namely.  You had "self.theWeight" in function Reading instead of "this."...

Happy Coding!

Comment: One more thing.  The only reason `self` works in the later code (below Editable data) is that it refers to [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self).  This is somewhat confusing.

Comment: wow thank you so much! i knew it was something small i was doing wrong.

Comment: self, as matthew was refering, is not an object you should play with.  It would be smart to hold your global objects within a namespace (var myapplication, or something like that), or within the DOM (jquery.data() objects)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(self.users()[0].theReadings()[0].theWeight();
```

I would recommend removing the 'thes'.  That's an uncommon style.

Comment: i tried adding the .theWeight() but it doesnt work. it kind of just breaks everything.